# How test Angular Salesforce page, body content using phantomjs

Tags: unit-test, angularjs

I'm trying to test a Salesforce page using Phantomjs, I'm able to get everything BUT anything inside my html-data-ui-view="" attribute. Is there anyway to get the body content?

And yes I've seen only one other question where this is mentioned, but there's no mention of the ui-view.